# What is the threading class if I just want to test and set a flag in a threadsafe manner?

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, multithreading

I just want to do a simple, though thread-safe, boolean test (and set)
so:

```
if(myBoolean==false)   //should not lock/wait!
{ 
     myBoolean=true;
     .....
}
else
{
     ....
}
```

I considered the following (although possibly incorrectly, so please correct me where I misunderstood)

- using the Lock { if(myBoolean)...  } construct seems like a overkill way to do it. And, it also locks the thread while it waits for the lock to become free. I don't want this.
- The AutoResetEvent class does have a concept of a boolean state, but it is used to signal another thread which is waiting. So not relevant in my case
- Semaphore class has a notion of a reference count (probably to throttle the amount of access to a resource?). So probably not what I'm after.
- Mutex class. As far as I understood, this is the same principal as the Lock primitive

Anyone have an idea what is the class/construct to do this in an efficient manner?

Comment: Why are you checking whether it's `true` and then setting it to `true` again?

Comment: If you want it threadsafe, you gotta loose some efficiency. Lock it.

Comment: @slaks: good point... fixed ;^)

Comment: @danail: Lock sets the thread in a wait state... I don't want this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider [Interlocked.CompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

The answer (`Interlocked.CompareExchange`) was already given, but here's my usage example:

```
private int _isDisposing;

public bool IsDisposing
{
    get
    {
        return this._isDisposing != 0;
    }
}

public void Dispose()
{
    // Side note: I may want to `return` instead of `throw`
    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isDisposing, 1, 0) != 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Dispose was recursively called.");

    try
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    finally
    {
        _isDisposing = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentations says "The return value of this method is the original value in location1, whether or not the exchange takes place.". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297966.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class, specifically for [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange.aspx).

Comment: @slaks: I don't know how my question could be any more specific. What is the .net equivalent of the atomic testandset (a well known concurrency pattern). I thought I explained this well.

Comment: Using Interlocked you can do what you call "testandset" in an atomic operation.

Answer (score 1):

To have a thread safe test and set operation the code have to block other threads. To avoid locking uneccesary, you can use the test-and-test-and-set pattern:

```
if (something) {
   lock(_sync) {
      if (something) {
         something = false;
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

The second test is needed to be sure that some other thread didn't change the value between the first test and the lock.

Comment: But since the double test is not atomic, it is still possible the Lock will set my thread in a wait state. I was really hoping for an atomic 'testandset' function.

Comment: Don't you also have to make sure that 'something' is volatile for this to be effective?

Answer (score 1):

For collections, "Test and Add" I use

```
    /// <summary>
    /// If h contains v then return true, else add v to h and return false.
    /// Thread safe on h.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="h"></param>
    /// <param name="v"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool TestAndAdd(HashSet<string> h, string v)
    {
        lock(h)
        {
            if(h.Contains(v))
            {
                return true;
            }
            h.Add(v);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then I can test and set like:

```
if (!TestAndAdd(usedCodes, mc.code))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue many times, and don't think that I could keep in mind that the last argument of Interlocked.CompareAndChange() is the comparand.
Here's what I came up with.

```
using System.Threading;

public class AtomicFlag
{
    public const int SETVALUE = 1;
    public const int RESETVALUE = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the current state of the flag.
    /// 0 means false (or reset).
    /// 1 means true (or set).
    /// </summary>
    private int Value;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an atomicflag with the specified default value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="initialValue">AtomicFlag.SETVALUE or 
    /// AtomicFlag.RESETVALUE. Defaults to RESETVALUE.</param>
    public AtomicFlag(int initialValue = RESETVALUE)
    {
        Guard.AgainstUnsupportedValues<int>(initialValue, "initialValue",
           new int[] { SETVALUE, RESETVALUE });
        Value = initialValue;
    }


    public void Set()
    {
        Value = SETVALUE;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Value = RESETVALUE;
    }


    public bool TestAndSet()
    {
        // Use Interlocked to test if the current value is RESETVALUE,
        // return true and set value to SETVALUE.
        //
        // From Interlocked.CompareExchange help:
        // public static int CompareExchange(
        //    ref int location1,
        //    int value,
        //    int comparand
        // )
        // where
        //  location1: The destination, whose value is compared with 
        //             comparand and possibly replaced.
        //  value:     The value that replaces the destination value if the
        //             comparison results in equality.
        //  comparand: The value that is compared to the value at
        //             location1. 
        return (RESETVALUE == Interlocked.CompareExchange(
            ref Value, SETVALUE, RESETVALUE));
    }

    public bool TestAndReset()
    {
        // If the current value is SETVALUE, return true and change value 
        // to RESETVALUE.
        return (SETVALUE ==
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref Value, RESETVALUE, SETVALUE));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implemented `TestAndSet` as a wrapper around `Interlocked.CompareExchange()`.

The gist of it is:

```
public static bool TestAndSet(
    ref int variable, int replaceWithValue, int testForValue)
{
    return testForValue == Interlocked.CompareExchange(
        ref variable, replaceWithValue, testForValue);
}
```

Available as [B.Atomics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/B.Atomics) NuGet package.